# Build an android app using Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I'd like to separate the [TensorFlow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) from the repo of Tensorflow.

Is there a way to do that without changing anything to the tensorflow repo ?

The final structure should be something like this:

```
my_project
|-- WORKSPACE
|-- my_android_app
|   |-- BUILD
|   `-- ...
|-- tensorflow
|   |-- tensorflow
|   |   |   |-- workspace.bzl
|   |   |   |-- tensorflow.bzl
|   |   |   `-- ...
|   |-- WORKSPACE
|   |-- BUILD
.    `-- ...
```

In other words, how to import Tensorflow repo as a package in bazel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literally copy the directory into your `my_project` directory, you can.  Then add the following lines to your `my_project/WORKSPACE` file:

```
 local_repository(
     name = "my_tensorflow",
     path = "./tensorflow", # Relative path to the tensorflow workspace
 )
```

Then you can depend on any targets from tensorflow in your project, e.g., `@my_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace.bzl`.

Take a look at Tensorflow's "serving" project, which does what it looks like you're trying to do: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/WORKSPACE.

Comment: I'm aiming to do the exact thing, separating android project from tensorflow to build upon with the same folder structure. When referring to tensorflow targets, I get the following error "no such package 'tensorflow': Package crosses into repository @org_tensorflow and referenced by '//android:libtensorflow_demo.so'"

Comment: I'm guessing that you're attempting to build https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d2ca961d742b7dbaebf6b7e31f6f6545fa702499/tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD#L19?  If so, this is in the tensorflow repo, so you cannot use the path above.  If you're having issues, please post a question that elaborates on what's in your BUILD file and what you directory structure looks like.

Comment: I've posted a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153199/building-a-tensorflow-based-android-app-with-tensorflow-as-a-repository