# Compiling a custom TensorFlow operation outside TF source tree

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I have a custom TensorFlow operation which currently sits inside `/tensorflow/core/user_ops` and uses the `tf_custom_op_library` bazel function in `BUILD`. I would like to separate it from the TF source tree and ship in an independent repository. How could I compile such operation?

Comment: Normally you make TensorFlow an external dependency, but right now there's an issue which makes this impossible -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6706

Comment: Also there's another issue, bazel.select() function isn't context sensitive to the workspace it's defined in there's a bunch of `bazel.select` in custom_op/cuda rules -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153199/building-a-tensorflow-based-android-app-with-tensorflow-as-a-repository

Comment: We've been building things in TF source tree, and then having a script extract the binaries for the pip package